# Storing variables with fs.readFile?

Tags: arrays, json, fs

I have a function that needs to parse a `.txt` file containing objects. It's not proper JSON since there are no commas and no surrounding array.

This is my current function:

```
module.exports = {
  bot_detection: function(input_file_path) {
    fs.readFile(input_file_path, 'utf-8', function(err, data){
       if (err) { throw err };
       data = "[" + data.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, ',').slice(0, -1) + "]";
       console.log(data);
    }
  }
}
```

This is some sample data inside the file path:

```
{"timestamp": 1487184625, "user": "Eric", "action": "navigate"}
{"timestamp": 1487184655, "user": "Bill", "action": "browse"}
{"timestamp": 1487184685, "user": "Eric", "action": "key press"}
{"timestamp": 1487184715, "user": "John", "action": "idle"}
{"timestamp": 1487184755, "user": "Tran", "action": "search"}
{"timestamp": 1487098049, "user": "Tran", "action": "click"}
{"timestamp": 1487098079, "user": "Eric", "action": "click"}
{"timestamp": 1487098109, "user": "Tran", "action": "click"}
{"timestamp": 1487098139, "user": "Bill", "action": "navigate"}
```

Since `fs.readFile` is async, then I can't create a variable outside and re-assign it to the data read. Is there a way I can store the converted JSON into a variable so I can manipulate it easier (with `map` for example)?

Answer (score 0):

JSON.parse() should convert the finished string to a workable object.

You can also eval() the string though doing so may have security issues as it will execute injected javascript that gets stored in the file.